# NullPointerException on button setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent

```
sample = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sampleButton);
sample.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

When I try to load my Activity, it throws a null pointer exception on the Listener. **Why**? I have defined my button variable globally.

```
Button sample;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your button `sampleButton` is probably not in the layout you passed to `setContentView()`. `findViewById()` can only find views that are currently displayed.

Comment: Yeah, `Button sample` seems NULL.

Comment: @Sam: i will mark this answer tomo... thanks... moving out now.

Comment: @theJava Ok, if you need more specific advice later I'm happy to help, but you'll have to provide some more information including the LogCat and the current layout.